# How do i pass data from one activity to another in android?

Tags: android

In one Activity, I enter the details like name,etc. into Edittexts. Now how do i pass these Strings to the other activity. The string values entered will vary from user to user.

Comment: what all you have tried so far ?

Comment: i tried using putExtras, but since i cant put two variables as the arguments, im stuck

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(youractivityfrom.this,
                        youractivityto.class);
                i.putExtra("key1", value);
                i.putExtra("key2", value);
                startActivity(i);
```

Comment: This is if I have just one value.Suppose I am using this app and in the text field i enter my name. Now how do i put my name into the value field without manually entering my name into the value field. If u are using the app, then ur name should be passed .

Comment: I dint get you what you are trying to say exactly, save your typed value into string then pass it with intent you can pass any number of value using intent